# Scraping more than one criteria

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I am handling with a problem I can't really solve. I am trying to get information out of a specific page using the selenium library. If I do have belows code, I do get the correct value.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DAI.DE?p=DAI.DE&.tsrc=fin-srch'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Startklar/Desktop/CFDS/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

articles = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.js-stream-content")))

for article in articles:
    try:
         date = article.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/ul/li[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/span[2]').text
         print(date)
    except:
        print("")
```

As soon as I am adding a second value to find and the code looks like this below I don't get any result at all:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DAI.DE?p=DAI.DE&.tsrc=fin-srch'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Startklar/Desktop/CFDS/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

articles = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.js-stream-content")))

for article in articles:
    try:
         date = article.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/ul/li[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/span[2]').text
         source = article.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/ul/li[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/span[1]').text
         print(date,source)
    except:
        print("")
```

How comes? What's the difference between copy xpath or copy fullxpath? And why do I only get one result or one result twice instead of all dates and sources on the site?

Comment: Wouldn't be using full xpath here but a smaller xpath related to article.

Comment: presence of all elements returns when it finds at least one element.  You're assuming it's finding all...  but even when you do get the array, it's not actually what you are looking for anyway.  You're giving it a full DOM path to a specific item, so there's really no need for "article in articles".  On top of that if this content is dynamically generated, that DOM path is probably variable.

Comment: It's dynamically generated with lazy loading.

Comment: what means "it's dynamically generated with lazy loading"?

Comment: When you scroll down it loads content.

Comment: I am aware of that. I think the command                  

articles = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.js-stream-content")))
makes sure that the whole page will be loaded or not?

Comment: and as a result he should have all the articles to srap or am I totally wrong on that?

Comment: It's looking for an element and not waiting for load.

Comment: does the 100 not mean that it is waiting 1 minute? I don't get that! What do I have to do that he is waiting for load?